# Different results from mysql query in app compared to website, Swift + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting different results from a MySQL query when using my app compared to just using a URL to get the results.

The following accesses the database and displays the username and userID for any username that contains the `$_GET` value, it works fine when accessing through URL, but when calling from my app it displays all users from the database.

Server side:

```
<?php
require("lib.php");
header('Content-type: application/json');
$username = $_GET['search'];
$search = "%$username%";
$result = query("SELECT username, userID FROM user_accounts WHERE username LIKE '%s'", $search);
if (!$result['error']) {
    if (count($result['result'])>0) {
        class Emp {
            public $success = "";
            public $result = "";
        }
        $e = new Emp();
        $e->success = 1;
        $e->result = $result['result'];
        echo json_encode($e);

    } else {
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"No users found"}';
    }
} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Connection error"}';
}
?>
```

App side:

```
protocol SearchUsersAPIProtocol {
    func didFindUsers(results: NSDictionary)
}

class SearchUsersAPI: NSObject {

var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()


var delegate: SearchUsersAPIProtocol?

func searchUser(search: String) {
    println("search string is \(search)")
    var post = NSString(string: "search=\(search)")
    var urlPath: String = "URL"

    var postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    var postLength = NSString(format: "%lu", postData!.length)

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData


    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)

    connection.start()
}


func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Connection failed.\(error.localizedDescription)")
}


func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    // Recieved a new request, clear out the data object
    println("connection did receive")
    self.data = NSMutableData()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
    // Append the recieved chunk of data to our data object
    println("connection")
    self.data.appendData(data)

}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    // Request complete, self.data should now hold the resulting info
    // Convert the retrieved data in to an object through JSON deserialization
    println("connection finished")
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    // Now send the JSON result to our delegate object
    println("results: \(jsonResult)")
    delegate?.didFindUsers(jsonResult)


}

}
```

Comment: Note to future readers: if `query()` just uses `sprintf()` internally, this code has a SQL injection vulnerability. Always bind your variables, using an up-to-date library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your app you `POST` the search query, so it's post variable. Use this to allow both post and get:

```
$username = $_REQUEST['search'];
```